# Infinite scroll with ng-if messes up order in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using ng-repeat to get some list items. That works. I am also ordering them, based on alphabet. I am doing that like this:

```
<li class="item" ng-repeat="schedule in Schedules | filter:scheduleSearch | limitTo:numberOfItemsToDisplay | orderBy: 'namesAlphabet' as names">
    Display some data
</li> 
<ion-infinite-scroll on-infinite="addMoreItem()" ng-if="Schedules.length > numberOfItemsToDisplay"></ion-infinite-scroll>
```

Now, I added the infinite scroll you can see below. I want to get these items after scrolling. That works as well *(although on iOS, it just shows them even before scrolling, but that's a different issue)*.

I am doing that like this:

```
$scope.numberOfItemsToDisplay = 10; // Use it with limit to in ng-repeat
$scope.addMoreItem = function(done) {
    if ($scope.Schedules.length > $scope.numberOfItemsToDisplay)
        $scope.numberOfItemsToDisplay += 10; // load number of more items
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete')
}
```

The problem is that the initially shown items (the first 10) are just randomly shown and are not obeying the `orderBy` which is stated in the ng-repeat. So what I want to do, is that it shows me the list items after scrolling while still ordering it as I stated in the `ng-repeat`.

My question is: how can I do / fix that?

Is there something I am missing in my code? I tried adding it to the `ng-if`, but that didn't work at all.

Comment: I believe if you're wanting the list to be re-ordered, you're going to have to reload the entire list and not just add to it.

Comment: How do you mean? So I should change the whole structure? Why is that?

Comment: what are you ordering by. is namesAlphabet a property on schedule?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed. It just checks the names of the list items and orders them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `limitTo` should be placed after `orderBy` (order is important).

```
<li class="item" ng-repeat="schedule in Schedules | filter:scheduleSearch | orderBy: 'namesAlphabet' | limitTo:numberOfItemsToDisplay">
    Display some data
</li>
```

Comment: Damn, so simple, yet so effective! Thanks mate!